# How to combine two array in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Array1 : { A , B , C }
Array2 : { 1 , 2 , 3 }

I need to combine of this array list like:

Combine array : 
{ 
  A(1),
  B(2),
  C(3)
}

How can I implement this?

Comment: It would be easier to see what you are trying to achieve if you showed your PHP code as an illustration.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i need in ios

Comment: Of course you do. But it is quite unclear what exactly you need to do in ios, so PHP code would help to understand it a great deal: somebody with the knowledge of both PHP and iOS would teach you how to "translate" it.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `NSDictionary`

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:array1
                                                 forKeys:array2];

NSString *value = dict[@"1"]; //value = @"A";
```